# Offset on driver via scripted expression

Tags: python, drivers

I am trying to rotate a set of limbs on a centipede all slightly offset from each other in a 360 degree cycle. Each one will have a driver with an offset, thus the centipede would walk as seen here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivWcwgfWR7Y

The turning of a main control wheel offsets the y-height of the target bone by x amount.

The driver so far is this

```
sin(abs(v*.25))*.9
```

where `v` (var) is the **z** rotation of main wheel, and drives the **y** height of bone. How can I offset the expression so that, say, plus %10 of rotation causes the next limb to lag or lead height by 10 percent?

[image: Example]

Note that the wheel is located toward center/root of centipede.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use self and a custom property**

[image]
*Offsets L to R, `-pi / 2, -pi / 4, 0, pi / 4, pi / 2`*

Using a simple example with 5 cubes as feet and another as the wheel.

[image]

Add a custom property to foot, if you are driving a pose bone add a custom property to the bone.

Helper script to add a custom property named "offset" (*edit to suit*) to all selected pose bones.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

propname = "offset"

for pb in context.selected_pose_bones:
    pb[propname] = 0.0 # set a float proprty
```

[image]

Drivers have a `use self` option. When on `self` in an expression refers to the object being driven.  The custom property on the object can be added to an expression as `self["prop"]` *Pick a better name than prop*.

'rot' is a variable set up as usual getting the local rotation of the spinning cube.  We offset that rotation by adding the value of the property to it.

```
abs(sin(rot + self["prop"]))
```

Comment: I'm implementing this now...gonna accept once its working. Are you using the new Blender beta? Some things seem different on my end.

Comment: Yes I'm using 2.8.  Everything mentioned is available in 2.79.