# How Use the rotation of a driver object to drive the 0-1 position of 12 driven objects

Tags: python, drivers, mathematics

[image: Driver and driven image]

I've specfied my question so its hopefully a bit clearer.
The idea is to use the rotation of a driver, to drive 12 driven objects.
This means that for every 30 degrees of rotation, a driven object goes from 0, to 1 and back to 0. Gradually.

What does this specificly look like for one driven object?

Driver rotates to 15 degrees. Driven object is on Tz = 0
Driver rotates to 30 degrees. Driven object gradualy moved to tz = 1
Driver rotates to 45 degrees. Driven object gradually moved to tz = 0

Driver rotation can be > 360
and only when it reaches the equivalent of 15-45 degrees, should driven object gradually move from 0, to 1, and back to 0

Comment: What do you mean by "activates from 0 to 1"? Should they shift or rotate? Could you add some "before" and "after" images?

Comment: Hi Lemon, Good point.

When driver rotates to 0 degrees. The first driven bone would translate in z from 0 to 1.
Then when driver rotates to 30 degrees. The first driven bone would translate back to 0, and the second driven bone would translate in z from 0 to 1.

Does that help?

Comment: Yes, much more clear. Does the driven bones belong to the same armature?

Comment: absolutely. And I've taken care of the driver creation itself, Its just that Im not really sure how to go about getting rotation converted to translation combined with not getting them all to go at the same time.

sorry if this question isnt more clear. if it would be helpful I could make a blend file to give a clearer use case

Comment: Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133920/15543  in that a single driver can be copied pasted that uses a custom prop of the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind editing the drivers for every object individually its quit simple.

```
radians((LOWER_LIMIT <= (abs(degrees(var)) % 360) < UPPER_LIMIT) * 90)
```

with:

> var = z rotation driver
> UPPER_LIMIT = minumum rotation of driver to rotate object
> LOWER_LIMIT = maximum rotation of driver to rotate object

How this works:

> The comparisons return either a value 1 (True) or 0 (False)

NOTICE:  for the modulo to work you have to anable Auto run python script.
And to make it work gradually (totates 360d):

```
radians(LOWER_LIMIT <= (abs(degrees(var)) % 360) < UPPER_LIMIT) * (abs(degrees(var)) % 360 - LOWER_LIMIT) * 6
```

And if you want it to rotate back in opposite direction:

```
radians((LOWER_LIMIT <= abs(degrees(var)) % 360 < UPPER_LIMIT) * (-(1 / 15 ** 2) * (abs(degrees(var)) % 360 - LOWER_LIMIT - 15) ** 2 + 1) * 90)
```

Completely unrelated:
-binary counter

```
radians( ( ( degrees(var) % 2**(Driven_Object_Number))>2**(Driven_Object_Number-1))* 90)
```

here it is counting to 128
[image: binary counter counting to 128]

Comment: And if you don't want to edit the drivers for every object individually, you can add a layer of indirection: drive an empty or something, and then use drivers or constraints from it to apply those changes to a large number of objects.  (Constraints are the easiest, can use "copy constraint to selected bone/object" operations.)

Comment: sorry i am a little confused, because this way you still have to set the individual drivers?

Comment: you set it once, for the empty, to drive some value off it.  Then for the rest of the objects, you can create simpler drivers without any script (like, by copy as new driver, paste as driver), or even better, use constraints to translate the action taken by the empty onto everything else.

Comment: Hi Alex, interesting tried it on the first 4 driven objects and that worked quite well.

Rotating beyond 360 degrees doesn't work just yet. Perhaps I overlooked something.
Switching from True to False is cool, but what I should've said was: gradually shift between those two states. Not sure if thats a tough call, but figure I'd ask

if needed I have the blend file ready as well.

Comment: @HenkKok, what do you mean exactly by shift between the two stages.
like at 15 degree being true and at 0 and 30 false, or at 0 false and gardually going to true at 30 degrees?

Comment: Hi Alex, What I tried to say was:  At 15 degrees, the first driven object is 0. Then as the driver rotates to 30 degrees,, gradually the driven object translates and reaches 1 at 30 degrees. And when the driver continues to rotate all the way to 45, the driven object gradually moved back to zero.

The current function almost has that. And it works with rotations beyond 360 as well. To my eye it starts to look like wizardry. My god what a combination. But its doing it!

Comment: just one more question,
do you want it to get back in oposit direction or do 360 flip:
(radians(0) <= (abs(var) %(2*pi)) < radians(30)) * ((abs(var) % (2*pi)) - radians(0)) * 6
(this is the 360 flip)

Comment: Hi Alex, I respecified the question to hopefully clarify things a bit. (see description on top)
A 360 flip sounds cool, but basicly the driven object would ideally move from 0, gradually to 1, and back to 0 whenever the driver goes from 15 degrees, to 30 degrees and then to 45 degrees.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks for helping out man. I could not do this without diving deeper into radians and complex expressions

Comment: Alex, that last one nailed it. 
I filled out all the drivers for the 12 driven objects
with the correct values and it works like a charm.

Thank you man! I`ll post the code in my original question so others can use it in the future, in case they need something like it.

Also, That binary counter, haha, what a cool idea.

Comment: Alex, sorry for asking an additional question.I have the setup working I realized something new.  The current setup has always ONE driven object moving.
This is not entirely correct. As the first driven object goes back down. The second object should already start moving. So its like with Phases. Currently each driven object is one phase apart. But what I realized is that I actually need them to be half a phase apart. I've updated what that looks like in my original question.

I can make this a new question, since its the second update to the original question :-)

Comment: No problem @HenkKok but actually the answer is the same. you only have to change the upper and lower limit, so first object 0 - 30, second 15-45, third 30-60, 4th 45-75 etc

Comment: Brilliant. Solved it. Thank you!